# Read Data from CSV and Put into Database

Tags: c, database, csv, sqlite

I have a table with 6 columns and i have CSV Export like this with 6 entries per Line

```
me;val1;val2;val3;val4;val5;
me;val1;val2;val3;val4;val5;
```

I need to read these entries and Insert it into the SQLITE3 Database.So inorder to parse the CSV I use

```
void readcsv()
{
    FILE* stream = fopen("input.csv", "r");

    char line[1024];
    while (fgets(line, 1024, stream))
    {
        char* tmp = strdup(line);
        printf("Field 3 would be %s\n", getcsvfield(tmp, 3));
        // NOTE strtok clobbers tmp
        free(tmp);
    }
}
//Used for parsing CSV
const char* getcsvfield(char* line, int num)
{
    const char* tok;
    for (tok = strtok(line, ";");
            tok && *tok;
            tok = strtok(NULL, ";\n"))
    {
        if (!--num)
            return tok;
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

So will i have to call getcsvfield(tmp, fieldnumber) again and again in the Insert Query like this or is there a cleaner and efficient way.

```
execute("INSERT INTO table(a,b,c,d,e,f) VALUES('%s','%s','%s');",getcsvfield(tmp, 1),getcsvfield(tmp, 2),....... and so on
```

Please advise.

Comment: First idea could be to have static variable in your getcsvfield which will remember last position in parsed line, just to not start over every time and use `strtok_r` with that variable. 
Second idea is to create prepare_insert_query function which will return, already prepared  "INSERT INTO table(a,b,c,d,e,f) VALUES('val1','val2','val3');" using string concatenation inside along with strtok

Answer (score 0):

A more efficient method would be to parse the line once, creating an array of pointers to the tokens. You can then pass the array entries to the `execute` function like this

```
execute("INSERT INTO table(a,b,c,d,e,f) VALUES('%s','%s','%s');",token[0],token[1],...
```

Here's an example that reads lines from a file, breaks the line into tokens, and then prints the tokens.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int getTokens( char *line, char *token[], int maxt )
{
    int i;

    char *ptr = strtok(line, ";\n");
    for ( i = 0; i < maxt; i++ )
    {
        if ( ptr == NULL )
            return i;

        token[i] = ptr;
        ptr = strtok( NULL, ";\n" );
    }

    return i;
}

int main( void )
{
    const int maxt = 6;
    char line[1024];
    char *token[maxt];

    FILE *fp;
    if ( (fp = fopen( "input.csv", "r" )) == NULL )
        return 1;

    while ( fgets(line, sizeof line, fp) != NULL )
    {
        int count = getTokens( line, token, maxt );
        for ( int i = 0; i < count; i++ )
            printf( "%d: '%s'\n", i, token[i] );
        printf( "\n" );
    }

    fclose( fp );
}
```

Comment: Thanks... but i keep getting `Segmentation fault (core dumped)`
'

Comment: This does not print anything!

Comment: @techno There's only two reasons for it not to print anything. A) The `fopen` returned `NULL`. B) The file "input.csv" has nothing in it.