# CSV Parsing - Second Field Returning Null Values

Tags: c, parsing, csv

I use the following code to parse this CSV

```
me;val1;val2;val3;val4;val5;
me;val1;val2;val3;val4;val5;
```

---

```
void readcsv()
{
    FILE* stream = fopen("input.csv", "r");

    char line[1024];
    while (fgets(line, 1024, stream))
    {
        char* tmp = strdup(line);
      //  printf("Field 1 would be %s\n", getcsvfield(tmp, 1));
        printf("Field 1 would be %s\n", getcsvfield(tmp, 1));
        printf("Field 2 would be %s\n", getcsvfield(tmp, 2));
        // NOTE strtok clobbers tmp
        free(tmp);
    }
}
//Used for parsing CSV
const char* getcsvfield(char* line, int num)
{
    const char* tok;
    for (tok = strtok(line, ";");
            tok && *tok;
            tok = strtok(NULL, ";\n"))
    {
        if (!--num)
            return tok;
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

But i keep getting NULL value in the second Field

```
Output:
Field 1 would be me
Field 2 would be (null)
Field 1 would be me
Field 2 would be (null)
```

What im i doing wrong?

Comment: isn't it like `strtok()` modifies the input?

Comment: @SouravGhosh Seems its the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> strtok(line, ";");

`strtok` modifies the string (in this case `line`) being passed to it. So you should not use the same `line` (returned from first call to `getcsvfield`) also during the second time you call `getcsvfield`, because after first call to `getcsvfield`, `line` now has different content.

Notice this is not an issue *within* the function `getcsvfield`, because when you pass NULL second time to `strtok` inside *that* function, it knows how to proceed with the modified input string in a correct way.

From [manual](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strtok/) about `strtok` parameters:

> Notice that this string is modified by being broken into smaller
>   strings (tokens).

Something like this should do the trick. This is the most "basic" approach, you can try other ones too. Leave the `getcsvfield` function as you had in your code initially, just on the caller side do:

```
char line[1024];
char buffer[1024];
while (fgets(line, 1024, stream))
{
    // char* tmp = strdup(line); not necessary in this case
    strcpy(buffer, line);
    printf("Field 1 would be %s\n", getcsvfield(buffer, 1));
    strcpy(buffer, line);
    printf("Field 2 would be %s\n", getcsvfield(buffer, 2));
    // free(tmp);
}
```

As it currently stands above, each call to `getcsvfield`, returns poitner to same memory address - `buffer`. For `printing` it works ok (because at the time of printing it shows what is there in buffer), but if you want to store result of each call to `getcsvfield` for later use, you may want to copy result of each invocation of `getcsvfield` to some different memory location each time.

Comment: @techno Copy `line` to a temporary `buffer` inside getcsv field, and work on that buffer

Comment: I just fot your edit.. before you removed it :) .. i know its not an efficient way i have another question regarding it .. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35594037/read-data-from-csv-and-put-into-database  the answer there does not work.

Comment: @techno My suggestion in above comment will fix one of the problems I mentioned in my answer (the one about `strtok` modifying input), you still need to verify if the parsing inside `getcsvfield` function is done correctly

Comment: It seems to be done correctly.. i will check and modify if necessary.

Comment: okay.. great.. but there was an error in the edit... the corrected line is `char buffer[1024]= {0};`

Comment: ah.. okay.. but i dont know what you mean... will you edit it?

Comment: @techno please check it now

Comment: Can you paste the whole method please

Comment: Thanks... but the variable `line` is a parameter... why do you declare it again... see `const char* getcsvfield(char* line, int num)`

Comment: @techno Where do I declare it once again? This: `const char* getcsvfield(char* line, int num)` `line` can be used inside function, outside yous till need one

Comment: sorry,that was a different error :) it worked fine.Thanks for your help.